# Activity indicator not working in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I've to play A video from server and it takes some time. So I've Written an activityIndicator and started animating it. but the activity indicator is not showing up until the video is playing. Firs I've hidden activity indicator later unhidden it and started animating but its shown when the video is started playing.

Here is my code:
for info `indicatorView is a UIView` and I've `indView is an UIIndicatorView` inside of UIView; And I'm using AV Player for playing;

Please Read Clearly that indicator view is showing up in the view, but the problem is not showing up when i Said start animating but after some time when video is started.

```
  indicatorView.hidden = NO;
  [indView startAnimating];
```

*//Here Indicator view must shown in VIEW but it's not showing up;*

```
  MediaItem *item = [allVideos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [playerModel playMyVideo:item];
```

*// now here after 5 sec when video is ready to play it's showing up*

What is the problem.
I've used dispach asynch in both the places but no use

Comment: Please change your indicator view's color. May be it is white so you can't identify it.

Comment: which player you are using to play the video?

Comment: AVPlayer is being used

Comment: Explaining why this isn't working requires a knowledge of how threads work. I'm happy to explain this at your request, but if you're just looking for a quick fix check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33209052/2057171

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one method like,

```
-(void) videoPrepareToPlay {
    MediaItem *item = [allVideos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [playerModel playMyVideo:item];
}
```

and call that method like,

```
   indicatorView.hidden = NO;
  [indView startAnimating];
  [self performSelector:@selector(videoPrepareToPlay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
```

It may be work for you..

Comment: Hahahaha beat you by 1 second exactly :D http://stackoverflow.com/a/33209052/2057171

Comment: You should use `inModes:@[NSRunLoopCommonModes]` parameter like I did in my code otherwise some UI elements (e.g. UIScrollView) will not be intractable during your 3 second delay. Also why use a 3 second delay and not a 0.0001 second delay?

Comment: Yes we can use as you mentioned in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I've used dispach asynch in both the places but no use

But is this code being run on the main thread? UI updates should be executed on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //UI code
});
```

Comment: Tried but not working... Gui dispatch is got its time when the player is completed its execution

Answer (score 2):

Change `[playerModel playMyVideo:item];` to

`[playerModel performSelector:@selector(playMyVideo:) withObject:item afterDelay:0.0001f inModes:@[NSRunLoopCommonModes]];`

Comment: @SUDHAKARRAYAPUDI what? This is the same as the accepted answer except I posted it first. How is this working sometimes but not all of the time, yet you accepted an answer posted after mine with the same code but magically works all the time?

Comment: Hey really I don't know. But somehow His code is working fine but yours is working sometimes not all the time...May be because of the extra method added by him. But I've voted up because of your contribution. And you down voted my question...I never mind. but thanks

Answer (score 1):

Execute the ActivityIndicator code using performSelectorOnMainThread and retrieve the video using background thread.

**ELSE**

Easy Fix:

Use this https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: I'm not willing to add any third parties, But thanks anyway

Comment: Hey albert common man. Because my client doesn't want any third parties